# Why doesn't the pin-it button work on this mobile phone?

Tags: pinterest

I have a mobile app that is being tested on a variety of devices.  The Pin-it is working on most of the devices -- except one.  It is one tester's iPhone while the same works on other iPhone, iPad and Androids.  One of the other working iPhones has the same settings (firmware, IOS, etc.) -- the only difference is the carrier TMO vs Sprint.  The TMO works the Sprint does not.

The working devices will allow the user to interact with the "pin button" -- drop-down select a board, edit the description and touch the "pinit" button to pin.

The not-working devices will be non responsive to the drop-down and "pinit" button.  Of course it interacts with editing the text, but that is a form textarea field supported by the bowser widget.

I have no idea why it could be carrier or device dependent.  I can appreciate if it is browser dependent or the javascript engine implementation.

I am in the early stages of troubleshooting, but hoping others have experienced and could offer guidance or ways to troubleshoot.

I have compared all the browser settings -- cookies, javascript-enabled, etc.

Following is the URL that is cleaned to protect my client's project.

```
http://m.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.myclientcompany.com/stuff/cf8742a4-93c1-4f0d-ad80-5b7537e1cb63&media=http://www.myclientcompany.com/stuff/~/media/Image%20Stuff%20Icon.jpg&description=Text that describes the stuff.
```

Comment: what kind of "not work" is it?

Comment: oops --- edited the description for @mnagel.

Comment: I think I have it narrowed down to an invalid URL format.  The description has spaces and if I convert to %20 it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not provide enough detail in my attempt to simplify.  The full URL has spaces in the description, such as, "delightful and fun to wear" and creating a malformed URL.  As soon as I encoded for percent-sign, as "delightful%20and%20fun%20to%20wear".  It worked on all of my test devices.